# How do you compile and run a project in Visual Studio when you have multiple source and header files involved in the same project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I mostly worked with linux env, new to visual studio. (If you are in Linux, you would use the make utility...)  How do you compile and run a project in Visual Studio when you have multiple source and header files involved in the same project? I have main.cpp, and few other source and corresponding header files, and when i built the project, I couldn't see an output although the project compiled fine and 'exited gracefully'. How do I tell Visual Studio that these files are part of the project?

Comment: if you answered your own question, shouldn't it be **an answer**?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a "blogging site" you put tutorials for others. You can answer your question ONLY if you have already asked it but nobody has answered, and then you found out the answer. In this case, you should answer your question in "Answer field" section, not in question field.

Comment: @arav: alright, click the "edited: time" on the answer, and copy the bunch I deleted and put it as an answer below.

Comment: @all: apolozise for the text as it was done in haste.. thnx to the others for refining the text..

Answer (score 0):

To do that:

Select Project -->

1. Add Existing Item....
2. You should be looking in the same directory where you saved the project/solution.
   Highlight the .h and .cpp files: date.cpp, date.h and main.cpp
3. Select "Add" to add the files to the project.

Result: Once I added the 'main.cpp' and other files in the project, it works fine and I am able to view the output.

References:

1 [http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/210/Lab1_VCIntro/]